# R: 3rd Wedndesday of a specific month using XTS

Tags: r, date, xts

I want to retrieve the third Wedndesday of specific months in R.

This is not exactly a duplicate question of [How to figure third Friday of a month in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354069/how-to-figure-third-friday-of-a-month-in-r) because I want to use either Base R or XTS.

The data is in x:

```
library(xts)
x = xts(1:100, Sys.Date()+1:100)
```

and I can retrieve wednesdays by using:

```
wed=x[.indexwday(x) %in% 3]
> wed
           [,1]
2015-09-30    6
2015-10-07   13
2015-10-14   20
2015-10-21   27
2015-10-28   34
2015-11-04   41
2015-11-11   48
2015-11-18   55
2015-11-25   62
2015-12-02   69
2015-12-09   76
2015-12-16   83
2015-12-23   90
2015-12-30   97
>
```

I haven't figured out how to get the third observation in each month of this wed vector using xts but there must be a way.

```
third=wed[head(endpoints(wed, "months") + 3, -3)]
```

returns a wrong result.

I have read the xts documentation and couln't find the right function there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I prefer rbm's solution this time because it is shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
library(xts)
x = xts(1:3650, Sys.Date()+1:3650)

x[.indexwday(x) == 3  & 
    .indexmday(x) >= 15 & 
    .indexmday(x) <= 21
  ]
```

If first Wednesday is on 1st then third is on 15th.

If first Wednesday is on 7th then third is on 21st.

So anywhere between 15th and 21st.

Answer (score 2):

Take your `wed` object, split it by month, then select the 3rd row. Then use `do.call` and `rbind` to put it back together.

```
R> # 3rd or last available Wednesday
R> wedList <- split(wed, "months")
R> do.call(rbind, lapply(wedList, function(x) x[min(nrow(x),3),]))
#            [,1]
# 2015-09-30    6
# 2015-10-21   27
# 2015-11-18   55
# 2015-12-16   83
R> # no observation if 3rd Wednesday isn't available
R> do.call(rbind, lapply(wedList, function(x) if(nrow(x) < 3) NULL else x[3,]))
#            [,1]
# 2015-10-21   27
# 2015-11-18   55
# 2015-12-16   83
```