# How to transform a text filed into a week (time series variable) in R?

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I have a data file which is of this form, which I am loading into R as a dataframe:

```
Week,Sales
"Jan WK01, FY14",99
"Jan WK02, FY14",754
"Jan WK03, FY14",841
"Jan WK04, FY14",722
"Feb WK01, FY15",846
"Feb WK02, FY15",927
"Feb WK03, FY15",940
"Feb WK04, FY15",661
"Mar WK01, FY15",729
"Mar WK02, FY15",916
"Mar WK03, FY15",1317
"Mar WK04, FY15",1415
"Mar WK05, FY15",1462
```

How can I transform the first field into something that xts() understands as a week, so that I can analyze the sales time series?

I want to avoid this error:

```
Error in xts(Data, order.by = Data$Week) : 
order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function inputs a `"Date"` class variable and outputs the `"Date"` of the next Monday.

```
nextMon <- function(x) x + (as.numeric(format(x, "%w")) - 1) %% 7
```

(A different version of that can be found in my answer here: [Extract first Monday of every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577812/extract-first-monday-of-every-month/34579743#34579743) and the corresponding function for the next Friday in the zoo package's [Quick Reference vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf)).

Now given the question's input string `x` (see Note below for `x` given reproducibly) we can derive the first of its month (`fom`)  and the week number (`wk`).  The date corresponding to a given first of the month and week number is then the next Monday on or after the beginning of the month if `wk` is 1, 7 days later if `wk` is 2, 14 days later if week is 3 and so on.

```
fom <- as.Date(sub("WK.*FY", "1 ", x), "%b %d %y") # first of month
wk <- as.numeric(gsub(".*WK|,.*", "", x))  # week number
nextMon(fom) + 7 * (wk-1)
```

giving:

```
 [1] "2014-01-06" "2014-01-13" "2014-01-20" "2014-01-27" "2015-02-02"
 [6] "2015-02-09" "2015-02-16" "2015-02-23" "2015-03-02" "2015-03-09"
[11] "2015-03-16" "2015-03-23" "2015-03-30"
```

Note that if the fiscal and calendar years are different then the answer would have to be further adjusted based on what the fiscal year end actually is.

If you prefer weeks starting on Sunday then replace the 1 in `nextMon` with `0`.

**Note:** We define the input `x` reproducibly here:

```
x <- c("Jan WK01, FY14", "Jan WK02, FY14", "Jan WK03, FY14", "Jan WK04, FY14", 
"Feb WK01, FY15", "Feb WK02, FY15", "Feb WK03, FY15", "Feb WK04, FY15", 
"Mar WK01, FY15", "Mar WK02, FY15", "Mar WK03, FY15", "Mar WK04, FY15", 
"Mar WK05, FY15")
```