# Finding the third Friday of a month and data table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to find the third Friday of a month for delivery date of the futures, I used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354069/how-to-figure-third-friday-of-a-month-in-r), `getNthDayOfWeek` from `RcppBDT` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppBDT)

data <- setDT(data.frame(mon=c(5:12, 1:12, 1:12, 1:4),
              year=c(rep(2011,8), rep(2012,12), rep(2013,12), rep(2014,4))))
data[, third.friday:= getNthDayOfWeek(third, Fri, mon, year)]
```

However I get this message: `Error: expecting a single value`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not specify a `by` clause in your transformation, `:=` is (presumably) trying to apply `getNthDayOfWeek` as a vectorized function.

This should work:

```
Data[
  ,third.friday := getNthDayOfWeek(third, Fri, mon, year)
  ,by = "mon,year"]
Data
#   mon year third.friday
#1:   5 2011   2011-05-20
#2:   6 2011   2011-06-17
#3:   7 2011   2011-07-15
#4:   8 2011   2011-08-19
#5:   9 2011   2011-09-16
#6:  10 2011   2011-10-21
#7:  11 2011   2011-11-18
#8:  12 2011   2011-12-16
#9:   1 2012   2012-01-20
```

---

Or, more generally, in case you have duplicate `mon,year` tuples in your object:

```
Data[,Idx := 1:.N][
  ,third.friday := getNthDayOfWeek(third, Fri, mon, year)
  ,by = "mon,year,Idx"
][,Idx := NULL][]
#   mon year third.friday
#1:   5 2011   2011-05-20
#2:   6 2011   2011-06-17
#3:   7 2011   2011-07-15
#4:   8 2011   2011-08-19
#5:   9 2011   2011-09-16
#6:  10 2011   2011-10-21
#7:  11 2011   2011-11-18
#8:  12 2011   2011-12-16
#9:   1 2012   2012-01-20
```